# How can I select related items within the same table in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table looking like this:

```
id | date       | related_id
 1   2018-01-01
 2   2018-01-01
 3   2018-01-02
 4   2018-01-05   2
 5   2018-01-06
```

A query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date='2018-01-01'` should produce the following result:

```
id | date       | related_id
 1   2018-01-01
 2   2018-01-01
 4   2018-01-05   2
```

How can I achieve that in one MySql query?

Comment: I appreciate the quick answers!
I have tried some of your suggestions. @Yogesh solution produces lots of false positives.
@forpas first example produces the correct result. However, in the real world the `WHERE` condition is a lot more complicated than a simple date check. I was hoping for a solution that solely depends on `related_id=id`.
Basically if the query result includes `row id 2`, then `row id 4` should be included as well, no matter how the `WHERE` was formulated.Also, the table includes millions of entries.

Answer (score 2):

Extend your `WHERE` condition to the `related_id`'s date:

```
SELECT * FROM table t 
WHERE 
  t.date = '2018-01-01'
  OR 
  (SELECT date FROM table WHERE id = t.related_id) = '2018-01-01'
```

or with a self join:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table t LEFT JOIN table tt
ON tt.id = t.related_id
WHERE 
  t.date = '2018-01-01'
  OR 
  tt.date = '2018-01-01'
```

or with EXISTS:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE 
  t.date = '2018-01-01' 
  OR
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table  
    WHERE id = t.related_id AND date = '2018-01-01'
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one "layer", you can do this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM theTable AS t
LEFT JOIN theTable AS rt ON t.related_id = rt.id
WHERE t.`date` = searchValue OR rt.`date` = searchValue
;
```

If there are an indefinite number of layers, and you have MySQL 8.0, you can use a CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE myCte AS (
SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE `date` = searchValue
UNION
SELECT t.* 
FROM theTable AS t 
INNER JOIN myCTE ON t.related_id = myCTE.id
)
SELECT * FROM myCTE;
```

*Disclaimer: I am more familiar with MS-SQL CTE's, so there could be some problems with that latter option.*

Comment: I just changed it to `select t.*`, rather than just `select *`. it will result in t values when t is on the date, or t's related row is on that date; which reflects the question's desired result. I'm not sure the data you are thinking of that would show extra results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.date = '2018-01-01' OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t.related_id = t1.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT table.* FROM table LEFT JOIN table related
ON table.related_id = related.id
WHERE
    table.date = '2018-01-01'
    OR related.date = '2018-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work with the date function:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=DATE('2018-01-01');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y')
```